# Creating a dynamic complex type in entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have created a stored procedure which returns columns dynamically , but i'm unable to import it into entity framework

Does anybody know how to import a stored procedure that returns columns dynamically

Answer (score 0):

EF doesn't support stored procedure with dynamic result set. The result set must be fixed for EF to map it to complex type / entity type.